# How to get the Timezone Name e.g (GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

Tags: angular7

In Angular 7, How to get the Timezone Name e.g (Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi) for (GMT+05:30) or any other ways to get the Timezone name only.

formatDate() with zzzz option is giving me the GMT+05:30 but how to get (Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Moment Timezone.

[Momemtjs timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

`moment.tz.guess()` would give you what you require

Comment: moment.tz.guess() is returning Asia/Calcutta but i need Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi